# Is stimulated emission an excluded possibility in blackbody radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, thermal-radiation

From what I have understood spontaneous emission is what causes most of the light around us. And that lasers are made by stimulated emission, one photon "stimulating" an atom to drop to a lower level.

If we have a group of atoms in a higher energy level, and let’s say some emit a photon of a particular frequency, regarding the following atoms that will emit photons of that frequency too, how can we exclude the possibility experimentally of these following photons not being due to stimulated emission, since a „stimulating photon“ is present in the ensemble that can start a chain reaction from the first atoms that by spontaneous emission emitted a photon of the right frequency? Why is this not the case in blackbody radiation, how do we know/or can we know for sure that all photons emitted in blackbody radiation is due to spontaneous emission?

Comment: What makes you think black body radiation does not include stimulated emission?  Einstein got the $A$ and $B$ coefficients—which describe the rates of spontaneous and stimulated emission, respectively—by using a semiclassical argument that the detailed balance of all types of emission and absorption had to lead to the equilibrium, black-body Planck spectrum.

Comment: @Buzz Thanks for your comment! Well, then it makes more sense. What made me think that? Books, professors... that aren't able to make clear what actually is going on.

Comment: SoLa:  when posting a question, please provide references for your stated claims or propositions.  That makes it easier for us to address what's valid vs. what isn't